# How to convert R Date into Excel numeric serial date?

Tags: r, excel

Excel stores dates internally as floating-point serial date. We know how to convert it into R - using `as.Date(var2, origin="1899-12-30", tz='UTC')`.

The question is: **how to convert it back into Excel**? I tried all the obvious things, but I still get a mismatch.

Comment: Things you tried? What mismatch you got?

Comment: The origin in Windows Excel is commonly 1899-12-30 but there are exceptions.  See the Other Applications section of the R Help Desk article in https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Answer (score 7):

One approach is, for example for the date '2017-05-15' :

```
d0 <- as.Date(0, origin="1899-12-30", tz='UTC')
d1 <- as.Date('2017-05-15')

d <- as.numeric(d1-d0)
# or in one line
d <- as.numeric(as.Date('2017-05-15') -as.Date(0, origin="1899-12-30", tz='UTC'))
print(d)
[1] 42870
```

In excel the date '2017-05-15' gives the same number when expressed as numeric serial date.